# Fetching string from access database and displaying it in message box using C#

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

I want to fetch the random string generated in the access DB and display it using message box.
eg: if i enter a name "xyz" the random number generated to the corresponding name should be displayed in the message box..
i tried these codes but its displaying the name entered in the textbox

```
command.CommandText = "insert into Booking(Flightno,sName) values('" + comboBox3.Text + "','" + textBox1.Text + "')";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
string query = "select Freightno from Booking where sName=" + "\"" + textBox1.Text + "\"";
command.CommandText = query;
MessageBox.Show(query);
//MessageBox.Show("Succesfully booked");
```

Thank you

Comment: _Freightno_ and _Flightno_ are two different fields or just a typo?

Comment: 2 different fields!
Freightno i auto generated in DB. i need to display it using message box

Comment: You should always use [parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, to get out anything from a database you need to do something with your command.
If you want to read something various options exists, but when you need only one value the best approach is using `ExecuteScalar`.

```
command.CommandText = "insert into Booking(Flightno,sName) values(@p1,@p2)";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", comboBox3.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", textBox1.Text);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

// Clear the parameters collection to reuse the same command
command.Parameters.Clear();
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", textBox1.Text);
// Change the commandtext to the new query
command.CommandText = "select Freightno from Booking where sName=@p1";
string result = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
MessageBox.Show(result);
```